# Multer S3 (v3) type error when implementing AWS SDK (v3) - missing properties from type 'S3'

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk-js, multer-s3, aws-sdk-js-v3

I'm in the process of upgrading my AWS SDK from v2 to v3 (`@aws-sdk/client-s3` v`3.496.0`). This includes upgrading `multer-s3` to v`3.0.1` to be compatible as stated by their [docs](https://github.com/anacronw/multer-s3?tab=readme-ov-file#aws-sdk-versions). But I'm getting the following type error when I'm trying to associate the instantiated `s3` object within `multerS3{}`.

`Type 'S3Client' is missing the following properties from type 'S3': abortMultipartUpload, completeMultipartUpload, copyObject, createBucket, and 106 more.ts(2740)`

With some Googling I see that `abortMultipartUpload` is part of [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Operations_Amazon_Simple_Storage_Service.html). I update the import from `S3Client` to `S3` but then I get a different type error at the same spot.

`Type 'S3' is missing the following properties from type 'S3': getBucketLifecycle, getBucketNotification, putBucketLifecycle, putBucketNotification, and 11 more.ts(2740)`

```js
import { S3 } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

const s3 = new S3({
  region: 'us-east-2',
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: 'foobar',
    secretAccessKey: 'fizzbuzz',
  },
});

export const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3, // <-- where the type error occurs regardless of using `S3` or `S3Client`
    bucket,
    key,
  }),
});
```

[image]

I believe I should be importing `S3Client` and not `S3` but what am I missing here?